# how to give dragging limitation to svg elements in Parent Div That means for Ex. the while dragging ellipse & rect elements didn't go outside the box

Tags: javascript, html, css, raphael

```
How to give dragging limitation to svg elements in Parent Div That means for Ex. the while dragging ellipse & rect elements donot go outside the box
```

See The Example => [Example Scenerio Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/RAJ_RN/Ln7pahuw/5/)

Comment: Can you make your example clickable?

Comment: Use Same example with same functionality just give limitation to svg element within the given **parent div border**

Comment: Hello @ Nirbhay Kundan  i have given Jsfiddle Link[ http://jsfiddle.net/RAJ_RN/Ln7pahuw/5/ ]  with example use it give solution .     Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
I have done with the limitation of SVG elements( Rect and Ellipse) but while dragging Text goes outside the the border of parent Div

see the Example
```

see the Example => [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/RAJ_RN/b4w3howq/2/)